# Alternative to the poll function to check new data in a FIFO

Tags: c, linux, posix, named-pipes, fifo

I'm writing a method to check if there is new data in a FIFO opened in `RDONLY` mode. Until now I was using the `poll()` function but I realized that the kernel on which the code will run doesn't have this function and it implements a subset of the Linux functionality and a subset of the POSIX functionality.

There are alternatives to the `poll` function?

(In particular, the machine is a BlueGene/Q and the functionalities offered can be found in the [Application Development Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247948.pdf) under the chapter Kernel access.)

**Review:**
Reading better the redbook I realized that the `poll` call is included in the kernel. I leave anyway the question because the reply can be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) is available, it should fit for your needs.

It performs a similar task to `poll(2)`.

Comment: I accepted this answer because, even if `select()` is not useful to my case, is a valid alternative to `poll()`. Thanks.